# Sequence number in field - OpenErp

Tags: python, orm, module, odoo

I need to load a sequence number in a specific field.

For this i'm using the `ir.sequence` model, as i have seen in other modules.

Problem is , it is not working yet, i don't know what i'm doing wrong here, perhaps the examples i'm using just work for a "title" field?

This is my code:

```
... _name = "product.product"
_description = "Product"
_table = "product_product"
_inherits = {'product.template': 'product_tmpl_id'}
_inherit = ['mail.thread']
_order = 'default_code,name_template'
_columns = {
    'codigo_n' : fields.char('Codigo Arancelario', size=64),
    'tec_esp' : fields.char('Especificaciones tecnicas', size=72),
    'qty_available': fields.function(_product_qty_available, type='float', string='Quantity On Hand'),
    'virtual_available': fields.function(_product_virtual_available, type='float', string='Quantity Available'),
    'incoming_qty': fields.function(_product_incoming_qty, type='float', string='Incoming'),
    'outgoing_qty': fields.function(_product_outgoing_qty, type='float', string='Outgoing'), ... code keeps going...
```

Here the interesting field is `codigo_n` whic is of type `char`i added the `_defaults` statement for this to work with `ir.sequence` as follows:

```
_defaults = {
    'codigo_n': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid,'product.product'),
}
```

Obviously i created the .xml sequence file, added to the `data` dependencies in the `__openerp__.py` file, and this is the code of the `custom_sequence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
    <data noupdate="1">
    <!-- Secuencias para product.product --> 
        <record id="seq_type_product_product" model="ir.sequence.type">
            <field name="name">Product</field>
            <field name="code">product.product</field>
        </record>
        <record id="seq_product_product" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Product</field>
            <field name="code">product.product</field>
            <field name="prefix">NG</field>
            <field name="padding">5</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

I think this is the correct way to setup this, i just need to make `codigo_n` to work with this sequence, any ideas of why it is not working?

I hope i've explained myself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility I see is that you many not have the xml/module updated properly.
Check "Settings / Technical / Sequences & Identifiers / Sequences" and look for the sequence you created.

Comment: Solved, i had to restart the server, the Sequence indeed appears in the "Settings / Technical / Sequences & Identifiers / Sequences" Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sequence dynamically in your **module_name_view.xml** using xml, it's a desired way to avoid manually creating dependents sequences during the module installation.

Here's the code to pute in your **module_name_view.xml** file :

```
<record forcecreate="1" id="seq_type_id" model="ir.sequence.type">
  <field name="name">my_seq</field>
  <field name="code">my_seq_code</field>
</record>
<record forcecreate="1" id="seq_id" model="ir.sequence">
  <field name="name">my_seq</field>
  <field name="code">my_seq_code</field>
  <field name="prefix">SEQ_</field>
  <field name="suffix"></field>
</record>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Already solved, but all new forms of problem solving are always useful, thank you very much!